# Unable to acquire JDBC Connection

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, hikaricp

I have a Spring Boot project with Hibernate and Hikari DataSource.
If i have some functionality with injected SessionFactory object to get session object, in few days I have such exception for any methods assosiated with db operations (only restarting solves this problem):

```
org.springframework.transaction.CannotCreateTransactionException: 
Could not open JPA EntityManager for transaction; nested exception is 
javax.persistence.PersistenceException: 
org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Unable to acquire JDBC Connection at
......
Caused by: java.sql.SQLTransientConnectionException: HikariPool-1 - 
Connection is not available, request timed out after 30001ms.
```

It seems to manual used session makes this problem. (I have similar project with the same configs and functionality, but without injected SessionFactory and Session...and I don't have such problem at all)

**application.yaml**:

```
spring:
  jpa:
    properties:
      hibernate:
        dialect : org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
        current_session_context_class: org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.SpringSessionContext
```

**DataSourceConfig**

```
@EnableJpaRepositories("com.my.project.config")
@Configuration
public class DataSourceConfig {

    @Inject
    private AppProperties properties;

    @Bean(name = "dataSource")
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        AppProperties.DatabaseProperties dbProps = properties.getDatabaseProperties();
        HikariDataSource dataSource = new HikariDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName(org.postgresql.Driver.class.getName());
        dataSource.setJdbcUrl(
            dbProps.getProtocol().concat("://")
                .concat(dbProps.getDbHost()).concat(":")
                .concat(dbProps.getDbPort()).concat("/")
                .concat(dbProps.getDbname())
        );
        dataSource.setUsername(dbProps.getUsername());
        dataSource.setPassword(dbProps.getPassword());
        dataSource.setMaximumPoolSize(30);
        dataSource.setMinimumIdle(30);

        return dataSource;
    }

    @Bean
    public SessionFactory sessionFactory(HibernateEntityManagerFactory hemf)   {
        return hemf.getSessionFactory();
    }
}
```

**LogRepositoryImpl**

```
@Repository
public class LogRepositoryImpl implements LogRepository {

    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    @Override
    public List<Log> getLogs(int offset, int count) {
        Criteria criteria = getSession().createCriteria(Log.class);
        return criteria.setFirstResult(offset).setMaxResults(count).list();
    }

    @Override
    public void save(Log log) {
        getSession().save(log);
    }

    private Session getSession() {
        return sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    }
}
```

dataSource.setMaximumPoolSize(30),
        dataSource.setMinimumIdle(); didn't solve this problem

Comment: Does it work for initial operations but then start timing out after some successful selects/saves?

Comment: Yes, the first time after starting the application, everything is fine.

Comment: I know time has passed but how did this end?

Answer (score 16):

We recently had this issue, but the Connection Pool Error message was eventually just baiting.

The real problem was a third-party system that did not accept more messages, thus blocking each thread. The connection never returned to the Pool if the thread had previously acquired a Connection from HikariCP. Hence, we had as many successful connections as Pooled Connections.

In such a case: Inspect the number of blocked Threads on the JVM with a tool of choice (any APM, VisualVM, or alike), and inspect where the blocked threads are halting with a Thread Dump.

Answer (score 5):

Sounds to me like an issue with your transaction boundaries, which aren't releasing the connections back to the pool. Could you try putting `@Transactional` on your `LogRepositoryImpl` class?

```
@Repository
@Transactional
public class LogRepositoryImpl implements LogRepository {
    . . . 
}
```

Comment: I do not use the LogRepositoryImpl directly. I have LogService and its implementation annotated with @Transactional with injected logRepository

Comment: Ah, could not have known that based on the info in your question. Are you running in a highly concurrent environment? You could try to increase your pool size if your app needs a lot of connections at once.

Comment: By default Hikari datasource is configured to have maximumPoolSize=10, I didn't solve my problem after setting maximumPoolSize to 30.
I think, I have the situation when in few days connectionPool doesn't have free connections at all (beacause as soon as I get this Exception, I can not get connection at all - only restarting solve this problem).
I have 5 scheduled methods and a lot of rest controllers.

Comment: That implies to me that you definitely have some operation within your application that isn't release connections back to the pool. Do you use the datasource anywhere else?

Comment: I have the exact same issue, everyday I have to restart the server and it's driving me crazy! I can't figure out the leak!

Comment: I'm facing the same issue, any solutions?

Comment: Add com.zaxxer.hikari: DEBUG log level which will add pg-pool - Pool stats (total=100, active=0, idle=100, waiting=0) connection logs

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong, but spring jpa by default has @Transactional right? that is If I use `implements JpaRepository`